# Woocommerce archive page for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy for Woocommerce with the following code:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function ess_custom_taxonomy_Item()  {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'collections',
    'singular_name'              => 'Collection',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Collections',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Collections',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Collection',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Collection:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Collection Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Collection',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Collection',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Collection',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Collection with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Collections',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Collections',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Collections',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'get_query_var'                  => true,

);
register_taxonomy( 'product-collections', 'product', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'ess_custom_taxonomy_item', 0 );
```

Everything works fine, I am able to add terms for the custom taxonomy and I am able to add products to each term, but, when I go to a term page, I get a 404 page.

I am looking for a way that when I go on a term page, I see the lists of products the same way I see the products when I go on the Woocommerce shop page.

Comment: Have you tried flushing your permalinks? Go to Options>Permalinks and then hit save.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot it worked! Cheers